# how can I cut audio to create a new audio?

Tags: c#

I want to cut some pieces of an audio to create a new audio with this pieces. What library should I use to get it?
I would like to do it with DirectSound, but I don´t get with it.
Can anybody gives a clue to me about this or says me a library for c# to use?

Comment: what audio formats do you want to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/).

Another option is to use the command line [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) and shell out to it.

Comment: +1 http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/09/trimming-wav-file-using-naudio.html Take a look at this specific NAudio example